# Database index for 'most recent' window function query

Tags: sql, indexing, mariadb

I have a `user` table and a `media` table.  The media table has a foreign key to the user table (`UserID`), as well as a `metaDate` (captured date) column.

I want to create a view that will show the most recently updated media associated to each user.  I'm currently trying to use a window function to create the view:

```
CREATE VIEW `user_last_media` AS
select `m`.`UserID` AS `UserID`,`m`
.`MediaID` AS `MediaID`
,`m`.`CaptureDate` AS `CaptureDate`
,`m`.`ThumbnailFile` AS `ThumbnailFile` 
from (
    with ranked_media as
    (
        select `m`.`UserID` AS `UserID`
        ,`m`.`ID` AS `MediaID`
        ,`m`.`metaDate` AS `CaptureDate`
        ,`m`.`thumbnailFile` AS `ThumbnailFile`
        ,row_number() over (partition by `m`.`UserID` order by `m`.`metaDate` desc) AS `rn` 
        from `media` `m` 
        where `m`.`shared` = 1 
        and `m`.`UserID` is not null
    )
    select `ranked_media`.`UserID` AS `UserID`
    ,`ranked_media`.`MediaID` AS `MediaID`
    ,`ranked_media`.`CaptureDate` AS `CaptureDate`
    ,`ranked_media`.`ThumbnailFile` AS `ThumbnailFile` 
    from `ranked_media` where `ranked_media`.`rn` = 1
) `m`
```

I have tried to apply an index, on the `media` table, using `UserID`, `shared`, `metaData`, `thumbnailFile`, and `ID`, but the performance of this view itself is not very good (~1 second for a query to get a single record by `UserID`).  NOTE that there are ~200,000 records in the `media` table and ~5,000 distinct `UserID` values.

Once i try to join this view with the user table to get more info for each user, the performance gets worse (3-4 seconds).  How can i improve my approach?  I'd like to apply proper indexing to get this query under .5 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

The common table expression adds unnecessary complexity. You could simplify this as:

```
create view `user_last_media` as
select `UserID` AS `UserID`, `ID` AS `MediaID`, `metaDate` AS `CaptureDate`, `thumbnailFile` AS `ThumbnailFile`
from (
    select m.*, 
        row_number() over (partition by `m`.`UserID` order by `m`.`metaDate` desc) AS rn
    from `media` `m` 
    where `m`.`shared` = 1 and `m`.`UserID` is not null
) m
where rn = 1
```

This *might* take advantage of an index on `(shared, userID, metadate)`.

You could also try and use a correlated subquery rather than window functions:

```
select `UserID` AS `UserID`, `ID` AS `MediaID`, `metaDate` AS `CaptureDate`, `thumbnailFile` AS `ThumbnailFile`
from `media` m
where 
    `shared` = 1 
    and `UserID` is not null
    and medaDate = (
        select max(m1.date)
        from `media` m1
        where `shared` = 1 and m1.`UserID` = m.`userID`
    )
```

Unrelated note: bacticks around each and every idenfier are just noise. Make your life easier! Use unquoted identifiers when creating your tables, so you never need to quote them later on in your queries.